# Unexpected #selector() Behavior in Swift-Objective-C Interop?

Tags: swift, objective-c, interop, pyobjc

I've encountered an unexpected behavior while working with Swift and Objective-C interoperability involving the `#selector()` expression. Typically, when using `#selector()`, I understand that it's common to specify the type (class or instance) that declares the method to help the compiler identify the correct selector.

However, I noticed that in certain scenarios, I can use `#selector()` without explicitly qualifying the selector with a type, especially when referencing methods within the same class or with `@objc` annotated members.

Here's an example that works as expected:

```swift
class MyClass: NSObject {
    @objc func myMethod() {
        let selector = #selector(myMethod)
    }
}
```

While the above code works fine, I encountered an unusual behavior when trying to use `#selector()` within a Swift extension of an `@objc` class or when bridging between Swift and Objective-C.

Could someone explain the underlying mechanics and potential pitfalls of using `#selector()` in these specific contexts? Are there any best practices or alternative approaches to ensure safe and consistent behavior across different scenarios?

I tried using the `#selector()` expression in various scenarios:

1. Within the same class without specifying the type.
2. Within a Swift extension of an `@objc` class.
3. When bridging between Swift and Objective-C.

I expected the `#selector()` expression to work consistently across all scenarios, either requiring or not requiring the type specification based on Swift's interoperability rules with Objective-C.

I encountered unexpected behavior where:

1. `#selector()` worked without specifying the type within the same class.
2. `#selector()` failed to work within a Swift extension of an `@objc` class or when bridging between Swift and Objective-C.

I'm looking to understand the underlying mechanics, potential pitfalls, and best practices for using `#selector()` in these specific contexts to ensure safe and consistent behavior.

Comment: 1. You never need to specify the type, same class or not. 2. You need to show a reproducible example where `#selector` failed.

Comment: In scenario 2, you would either need to define both the class and the method as `@objc`, or use the `@objcMembers` qualifier on the class. E.g., see [What is the @objcMembers attribute?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objcmembers-attribute) But, like HangerRash said, we would need to see an example of where it is not working for you.

Comment: Re “I’m looking to understand the underlying mechanics, potential pitfalls, and best practices for using `#selector()` in these specific contexts to ensure safe and consistent behavior” … That is all a bit broad. But I would refer you to the relevant section in _The Swift Programming Language,_ namely “Language reference” » “Expressions” » “[Selector Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Selector-Expression)”.